# Wordpress website is not loading the header images

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, wordpress-theming

I have configured the wordpress website in EC2 instance
I accessed the wp-config.php file and edited the url sturcture from http to https
but the header images in the website are not getting loaded

what else should i do to get the images displayed?
shall i try the reset from the appearance section or something else?
I gone through many such queries before posting this question but still not able to resolve

I can see theme folder and then assets folder -> images folder , how can i change the image in the themes folder through filezilla?

Comment: you could use a plugin like "Better search and replace" to perform a massive search and replace operation against your DB, looking for `http://www.yoursite.com` and replacing with `https://www.yoursite.com`

Comment: @GrafiCode I can see theme folder and then assets folder -> images folder , how can i change the image in the themes folder through filezilla?

Comment: it can't be done via filezilla, if you switched you website from HTTP to HTTPS, then you have to update URLs in your DB.

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks, but can you suggest me how can i access the DB and update the urls?